# populate list with for loop viewmodel

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

Just wondering if anyone can help with this problem.  I have a viewmodel which populates a dropdownlist.  I was just wondering if it's possible to change my code below so that I can use a for loop to populate the list.

ViewModel

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> numberOfAdults { get; set; }
```

Controller

```
numberOfAdults = new[]
                {  
                    new SelectListItem {Value = "1", Text = "1"},
                    new SelectListItem {Value = "2", Text = "2"},
                    new SelectListItem {Value = "3", Text = "3"},
                    new SelectListItem {Value = "4", Text = "4"},
                    new SelectListItem {Value = "5", Text = "5"},
                    new SelectListItem {Value = "6", Text = "6"},
                    new SelectListItem {Value = "7", Text = "7"},
                    new SelectListItem {Value = "8", Text = "8"},
                    new SelectListItem {Value = "9", Text = "9"},
                    new SelectListItem {Value = "10", Text = "10"}
                }
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.selectedAdultValue, new SelectList(Model.numberOfAdults, "Value", "Text"), null, new {@id="NumerOfAdults" })
```

Something like the following is what I would like, but not sure where to put it in model or controller.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    i;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be as simple as:

```
numberOfAdults = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(x => new SelectListItem
{
    Value = x.ToString(),
    Text = x.ToString()
});
```

or if you really want to use a `for` loop (I don't see why would you want that but anyway):

```
var result = new List<SelectListItem>();
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    result.Add(new SelectListItem { 
        Value = x.ToString(),
        Text = x.ToString() 
    });
}
numberOfAdults = result.ToArray();
```

Comment: Hi Darin, the reason I was going to use for loop was because I did not know you could use Enumerable.Range like your example